I am trying to use D3 libraries but not in a framework
I have this "borrowed" code , I am trying to get working I know that the original dev installed these D3 libs using npm "npm install d3-array"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style='height: 100%;'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />

    <title>Bookmarks Treemap</title>
    <!-- BUG: The following stylesheet cannot be @import-ed in anothere CSS file for some reason -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='chrome://global/skin/in-content/common.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/_styles/style.css' />
    <!--
    D3 licensed under the ISC License
    Copyright © 2010–2024 Mike Bostock
    License text: https://spdx.org/licenses/ISC.html
    -->




    
    <script src='/node_modules/d3-array/dist/d3-array.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/node_modules/d3-color/dist/d3-color.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/node_modules/d3-format/dist/d3-format.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/node_modules/d3-hierarchy/dist/d3-hierarchy.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/node_modules/d3-interpolate/dist/d3-interpolate.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/node_modules/d3-scale/dist/d3-scale.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/node_modules/d3-scale-chromatic/dist/d3-scale-chromatic.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/node_modules/d3-selection/dist/d3-selection.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/node_modules/d3-time/dist/d3-time.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/node_modules/d3-time-format/dist/d3-time-format.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/node_modules/internmap/dist/internmap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/options_default.js'></script> 
    <!-- Extension's default options -->



    <script src='js/script.js'></script>
</head>
<body style='margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;'>
    <svg id='treemap'></svg>
</body>
</html>

but I would like to just have links to online CDNs like this
    <script type="module">
import {min} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-array@3/+esm";
const m = min(array);
</script>

<script type="module">
import {rgb} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/d3-color@3";
const steelblue = d3.rgb("steelblue");
</script>

<script type="module">
import {format} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/d3-format@3";
const f = format(".2s");
</script>

<script type="module">
import {treemap} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/d3-hierarchy@3";
const tree = treemap();
</script>

<script type="module">
import {interpolateRgb} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/d3-interpolate@3";
const interpolate = interpolateRgb("steelblue", "brown");
</script>

<script type="module">
import {scaleLinear} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/d3-scale@4";
const x = scaleLinear();
</script>

<script type="module">
import {selectAll} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/d3-selection@3";
const div = selectAll("div");
</script>

<script type="module">
import {timeDay} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/d3-time@3";
const day = timeDay();
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/internmap@2.0.3/dist/internmap.min.js"></script>

but I am missing entries for
any ideas on how I can do this correctly, do I need it to be in a framework?
